# How to send email via vb.net catch exception with outlook programmatically?

Tags: vb.net, outlook

I am working on vb.net service application and application hosting in to the server running daily, sometimes service is stopped because exception is raising.

How to send email via vb.net issue (String)  with outlook programmatically?

Comment: Your service should not stop when an exception is thrown. You should attempt to log the error and carry on using a some recovery logic.

Comment: server is locating another place we need identify the error using mail concept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this to send via outlook. Just reference the Microsoft Outlook DLL

```
    Private Shared Sub SendMail(pMessage As String)

        Dim objMissing As Object = Type.Missing
        Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application = Nothing
        Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace = Nothing
        Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem = Nothing

        Try
            ' Start Microsoft Outlook and log on with your profile.
            ' Create an Outlook application.
            objOutlook = New Outlook.Application()

            ' Get the namespace
            objNS = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

            ' Log on by using a dialog box to choose the profile.
            objNS.Logon(objMissing, objMissing, False, False)

            ' create an email message
            objMail = CType(objOutlook.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem), Outlook.MailItem)

            ' Set the properties of the email.
            With objMail
                .Subject = "Subject Line"
                .To = "emailaddress@domain.com"
                .Body = pMessage
                .Display(True)
            End With

        Catch ex As Exception

        Finally
            ' Manually clean up the explicit unmanaged Outlook COM resources by  
            ' calling Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject on all accessor objects. 
            ' See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317109.

            If Not objMail Is Nothing Then
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(objMail)
                objMail = Nothing

            End If

            If Not objNS Is Nothing Then
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(objNS)
                objNS = Nothing

            End If
            If Not objOutlook Is Nothing Then
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(objOutlook)
                objOutlook = Nothing

            End If

        End Try

    End Sub
```

MSDN has a lot of info on this as well.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865816.aspx

Answer (score 1):

First, you should cath your errors, not let your service crash.  Second, you can use the [System.Net.Mail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.aspx) namspace to send mail.  You will want to create a MailMessage and send it through a SMTPClient.  Each will give you examples.